# g++ error: Class hos no member named

Tags: c++, oop, g++

I am playing around with my raspberry pi and the gpio. It's been going good and I am now trying to make a led light lit up every time a moving rectangle hit a edge of the screen.

To help with the turning the led on and off i have a class BlinkLED

```
#pragma once

#include "GPIOClass.h"

class Blienter code herenkLED
{
 public:
  BlinkLED(string gpionum);

  void update(float dt);
  void setOnfor(int ms);
  void finish();

 private:
  GPIOClass m_LED;
  int m_time2Shine;

};
```

in another file called Morph.cpp i try to run setOnFor(1000)

```
#include "Morph.h"
#include "BlinkLED.h"

template <typename T>
Morph<T>::Morph()
{
};

template <typename T>
Morph<T>::Morph(T min, T max, T v)
  : m_min(min)
  , m_max(max)
  , m_v(v)
  , m_cycles(0)
  , m_LED(NULL)
{
  m_current = getRandom(min, max);
  m_period = getRandom(min, max);
  m_flip = (getRandom(0, 1) > 0);
};
template <typename T>
void Morph<T>::setLED(BlinkLED* LED)
{
  m_LED = LED;
}

template <typename T>
T Morph<T>::update(float dt)
{
  if(m_current >= m_max)
    {
      m_flip = true;
      if(m_LED)
    m_LED->setOnFor(1000);
    }
  else if(m_current <= m_min)
    {
      m_flip = false;
      if(m_LED)
    m_LED->setOnFor(1000);
    }
  else if(m_cycles >= m_period)
    {
      m_flip= !m_flip;
      m_period = getRandom((int)m_min, (int)m_max);
      m_cycles = 0;
    }

  float direction = m_flip ? -1.0 : 1.0;
  m_current += direction * (T)getRandom((T)0, (T)m_v);
  m_cycles += 1;


  return m_current;

};


template class Morph<int>;
template class Morph<float>;
```

When I do this i get 2 errors, one for each setOnFor(1000)
    Morph.cpp:34:9 error: class BlinkLED has no member named setOnfor
    Morph.cpp:40:9 error: class BlinkLED has no member named setOnfor

Anyone having any ideas? I really want to see this work:D

The whole code can be found at 
https://github.com/Reicher/FlyingCubes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function declaration and definition are named `setOnfor`, while you call a function called `setOnFor`. Identifiers in C++ are case-sensitive. You need to pick one and be consistent.

Comment: I looked over and over again at the code without finding it! Must get a bigger tv or better glasses i guess:) thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Comment: @user1286316 Glad I could help. On Stack Overflow, we say thanks by accepting answers (so don't forget!). :)

Comment: @user1286316 I should have a play with my Raspberry Pi too. :)